# extjs vtype does not work on textarea

Tags: javascript, extjs

ok , I have a vtype for enslish and sign only that looks like this:

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
excel: function (v) {
    return /^.*.(xls)$/.test(v);
},
excelText: 'Must be an *.xls file',
englishOnly: function (v) {
    return /^[a-z0-9,\.\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\<\>]*$/.test(v);
},
englishOnlyTest: 'Must be English letters'
```

});

now I have a form that looks like this:

```
new Ext.FormPanel({
    id: 'add-label-form',
    url: hp,
    frame: true,
    baseParams: { actionName: 'AddLable' },
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    labelWidth: 70,
    items: [{
        id: 'tbKey',
        fieldLabel: localize.key,
        allowBlank: false,
        name: 'tbKey',
        anchor: '100%'
    }, {
        id: 'tbHebrewTran',
        fieldLabel: localize.hebrew,
        allowBlank: false,
        name: 'tbHebrewTran',
        anchor: '100%'
    }, {
        id: 'tbEnglishTran',
        fieldLabel: localize.english,
        allowBlank: false,
        name: 'tbEnglishTran',
        anchor: '100%'
    }, {
        id: 'tbDescription',
        xtype: 'textarea',
        vtype:'englishOnly',
        fieldLabel: localize.description,
        allowBlank: true,
        name: 'tbDescription',
        anchor: '100%'
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: localize.submit,
        formBind: true,
        handler: onAddLabelSubmitClick
    }, {
        text: localize.reset,
        handler: function () {
            var f = Ext.getCmp('add-label-form').getForm();
            f.reset();
        }
    }]
})
```

The vtype handler is called and returns false as expected but the form is still valid and no alert is displayed on the screen...
why is that?

Comment: thanks for that only now noticed that... opsss :)

Comment: No worries, thanks for taking the time to do that. I posted an answer that should help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to include `monitorValid: true` in your `FormPanel` config.

Here's a comment from the API that explains the config option in more detail:

> monitorValid  : Boolean
>
> If true, the form monitors its
>   valid state client-side and regularly
>   fires the clientvalidation event
>   passing that state.
>
> When monitoring valid state, the
>   FormPanel enables/disables any of its
>   configured buttons which have been
>   configured with formBind: true
>   depending on whether the form is valid
>   or not. Defaults to false.

With this set you should see the Button enabled/disabled and a red outline around whatever field the `vtype` applied to.

**Update:**

I noticed that your text variable for `englishOnly` is defined as **englishOnlyTest**, and I think it should be defined as **englishOnlyText** (you spelled "test" instead of "text"). If I recall correctly the framework expects to see *text* appended to the string that you want to use for the returned text. This may be why you're not seeing any red outline or popup text.

Comment: thanks for your replay but that didn't do it, the description text area fires the validation check but still no visual red outline or anything...

Comment: Check out my updated answer, this could be the cause of your issue.